# Inserting elements into a child node, based on a condition

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML

```
XElement xe = 
   new XElement("Schedule",
      new XElement("Team",
         new XElement("Name", "SomeName"),
         new XElement("Dates"),
            new XElement("Game",
               new XElement("Bench"),
               new XElement("Date")
            )
      )
  );
```

Eventually i'll want to add to the Bench and Date field.

I've tried something like:

```
foreach(Name name in names)
{
    doc.Element("Schedule").Element("Team").Element("Dates")
       .Elements()
       .FirstOrDefault(item => (string)item.Parent.Element("Name") == name.TeamName)
       .Add(
          new XElement("Game",
             new XElement("Bench", "SomeBench"),
             new XElement("Date", SomeDate.ToShortDateString())
           )
        );
}
```

I get an Object not set to an instance of an object error.

Any help would be great

EDIT: Forgot to mention that the insertions would happen with a loop

My End result would end up something like:

```
<Schedule>
   <Team>
      <Name>SomeName</Name>
       <Dates>
         <Bench>SomeBench</Bench>
         <Date>12/10/2012</Date>
       </Dates>
   </Team>
   <Team>
      <Name>SomeName2</Name>
       <Dates>
         <Bench>SomeBench2</Bench>
         <Date>12/13/2012</Date>
       </Dates>
   </Team>
   <Team>
      <Name>SomeName3</Name>
       <Dates>
         <Bench>SomeBench3</Bench>
         <Date>12/16/2012</Date>
       </Dates>
   </Team>
</Schedule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original OP's code could have an exception by several reasons:

1. In `doc.Element("Schedule").Element("Team").Element("Dates")` the segment `Element("Schedule")` is extra, if `doc == xe`, i.e. `Schedule` is the root xml element.
2. `.Elements()` segment is extra as the `Dates` element in `xe` does not contain any child elements.

The question is very confusing to me. Nevertheless I'll try to speculate.

```
foreach (var dates in doc.Elements("Team")
                         .Where(t => names.Any(n => n.TeamName == t.Element("Name").Value))
                         .Select(t => t.Element("Dates")))
{
    dates.Add(
            new XElement("Bench", "SomeBench"),
            new XElement("Date", SomeDate.ToShortDateString())
        );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're closer than i ever got...but the problem is it only ever does the first <Game><Bench></Bench>...</Game> of the file.

I need it too cycle through the 5 entries and add a <Game><Bench></Bench> for each

Comment: @AdamSweeney and another time